# MySQL ifNull vs isNull?

Tags: mysql

What is the basic difference between IFNULL and ISNULL in MySQL, and how can they provide an optimized solution for handling null values? I have been using an IF condition every time, but I'm looking for a more efficient approach.

So what I want is to use functions depending on the needs in the project as writing everytime IF is not an optimized solution.

Comment: please show some example of query (or sql code), so we can advise which functions to use

Comment: `ISNULL()` returns boolean value always, and it cannot return NULL. `IFNULL()` can return a value of any general type (MySQL uses the datatype which is the most common for both operands)? and it can return NULL.

Answer (score 2):

They server two completely different functions.

ISNULL(value) is a boolean operator that returns 1 or 0 depending on whether or not the value passed in is null.  It can be used in if and case statements to determine logic flow. Example:

```
SELECT OrderID, 
CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(AmountDue) THEN "Paid in full"
    WHEN DATE(DueDate) < date(NOW()) THEN "Order is past due"
    ELSE CONCAT("Order is due on ", CONVERT(VARCHAR, DueDate, 121))
END
FROM OrderDetails;
```

IFNULL(value1, value2) is used to handle a situation where you want one value, unless it is null, in which case you want a second value. Example:

```
select IFNULL(MiddleName, "No Middle Name") from customers
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, ISNULL simply checks if a value is null or not.  IFNULL acts like COALESCE and will return the 2nd value if the first value is null.

Are you perhaps mistaking ISNULL in SQL Server as the one in MySQL?  In SQL Server ISNULL is the same as IFNULL in MySQL.